# How to write a plugin which depends on a task from another plugin?

Tags: plugins, sbt

There is a great sbt plugin [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph/), which provides a `dependencyTree` task to show the dependencies.

I want to write a sbt plugin which depends on it, but always fails.

**build.sbt**

```
sbtPlugin := true

name := "my-sbt-plugin-depends-on-another"

version := "0.1.2.1"

organization := "test20140913"

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.5")
```

**src/main/scala/MySbtPlugin.scala**

```
import sbt._

object MySbtPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("hello task from my plugin")
    lazy val hello2 = taskKey[Unit]("hello task from my plugin2")
  }

  import autoImport._

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin

  val helloSetting = hello := println("Hello from my plugin")

  val helloSetting2 = hello2 := {
    println("hello2, task result from another plugins:")
    println(net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.dependencyTree.value)
    println("=========================================")
  }

  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    helloSetting, helloSetting2
  )

}
```

Then I published it to local, and use it in another project:

**build.sbt**

```
name := "sbt--plugin-test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

**project/plugins.scala**

```
logLevel := Level.Info

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.5")

addSbtPlugin("test20140913" % "my-sbt-plugin-depends-on-another" % "0.1.2.1")
```

When I run `sbt` on the later project, it reports:

```
Reference to undefined setting:

  *:dependencyTree from *:hello2 (/Users/twer/workspace/my-sbt-plugin-depends-on-another/src/main/scala/test20140913/MySbtPlugin.scala:38)
     Did you mean provided:dependencyTree ?

    at sbt.Init$class.Uninitialized(Settings.scala:262)
    at sbt.Def$.Uninitialized(Def.scala:10)
    at sbt.Init$class.delegate(Settings.scala:188)
    at sbt.Def$.delegate(Def.scala:10)
```

Where is wrong?

PS: The plugin code is here: https://github.com/freewind/my-sbt-plugin-depends-on-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dependencyTree` is only defined for specific configurations (well [all of them](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph/blob/v0.7.5/src/main/scala/net/virtualvoid/sbt/graph/Plugin.scala#L85)), but it automatically delegates to `Compile` in the shell.

Try defining `hello2` like so:

```
  val helloSetting2 = hello2 := {
    println("hello2, task result from another plugins:")
    import net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.dependencyTree
    println((dependencyTree in Compile).value)
    println("=========================================")
  }
```